# IBM x3400 M3: hangs on "UEFI Platform Initialization"

Tags: ibm

I am trying to set up an IBM x3400 M3 machine.

However, every time I boot and reboot, the machine displays: "UEFI Platform Initialization" for a while and nothing happens. Even the error LED gets on.

I've tried all the followings from the official source:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system-hangs-startup-message-uefi-platform-initialization-ibm-system-x

Workaround 1

For this one, I don't seem to find the "LPD Panel" neither the reset button, maybe I missed something

Workaround 2

I tried to add a jumper on the 2-3 pin on the jumper 29, but it only refused to boot. The power button did no longer work, therefore I removed it.
Further on, there was no jumper, to begin with, I fetched one from another computer, however no result.

Workaround 3

I remove the CMOS waited and put it back just as it is written, no luck.

I've also tried to play the memory in it. I tried the following combinations:
1 & 3, 1 & 4, all the slots an only in slot 1.

The server used to work around 6 months ago. Until then I haven't boot it. However, I added another CPU, which after some hours of booting/stopping the server and removing it, I realized that the server was not accepting it. However, now it hangs at the message above.

Any other suggestions or any way to debug it?

Comment: Have you check the hardware log (system event list) in the Integrated Management Module web interface? This is accessible via the management port.

Comment: How do we do that? I've read that there is some debugging thing indeed. Would you have a link or a source for me, please? I am kind of new with those things.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-integrated-management-module-users-guide-english-ibm-system-x-and-bladecenter

Comment: There is an ethernet port at the back of the server : https://youtu.be/20t8F4Xe0I8

Comment: Alright, I will give it a look. Thank you for your new leads!!

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi, I just plugged an ethernet cable in the "SYS MGMT" port and in the ethernet port 1, but no luck for both. I can't even seem to configure the IMM as in the youtube video. In the video/doc, it shows a white panel with the IBM logo, but mine hangs up a "UEFI platform Initialization". I don't even see the panel appear at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110216/discussion-between-atrashintheworld-and-mircea-vutcovici).